# Magento 2: How to add custom field in contact page

Tags: magento2, contact-us

I have added in `Magento_Contact` module custom field with order number:

```
                <div class="field telephone">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Your Phone') ?>" name="telephone" id="telephone"
                               title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                               echo __('Phone Number') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                    <div class="field ordernumber">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Order Number') ?>" name="ordernumber" id="ordernumber"
                               title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                               echo __('Order Number') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**screen:**
https://prnt.sc/s5fgtu

But when I sent a message via this form after filling this custom field (order number), when I receive a message from this contact module then this field is not displayed.

**screen:** https://prnt.sc/s5fh54

Any solution how to do?

Comment: custom filed not received  in email ???

Comment: Just after filling this custom field (order number), when I receive a message from this contact module, I can't see this field. You can check screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is correct :-

```
<div class="field ordernumber">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Order Number') ?>" name="ordernumber" id="ordernumber"
                               title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                               echo __('Order Number') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Now, go to `MARKETING > Communication > Email Templates` in the Magento Admin section. Click "Add New Template" and from the "Template" dropdown box select "Contact Form" then "Load Template". Under template content you will see:

```
{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
{{trans "Phone Number: %telephone" telephone=$data.telephone}}
{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}
```

Add your new field and this code :-

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table class="message-details">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Name"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Email"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Phone"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.telephone}}</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
           <td><strong>{{trans "ordernumber"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.ordernumber}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p><strong>{{trans "Message"}}</strong></p>
<p>{{var data.comment}}</p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

And save template. Now you need to tell Magento to use this new template for the Contact form. Go to `STORES > Settings > Configuration > General > Contacts` and select "Contacts". Under "Email Options", select your new template under the "Email Options" > "Email Template" dropdown box. Click on Save Button.

Hope help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Thanks. Working perfect :-)